# How do I list Quartz running jobs in java/struts2

Tags: java, struts2, quartz-scheduler

I wanted to list all the Quartz's jobs, which are running on background. I'm using following code, but I'm not getting any list.

```
 public class RunningJobs {

    public void getJobList() throws SchedulerException {

        Scheduler schedule = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        System.out.println(schedule.getJobGroupNames().size()+" "+schedule.isShutdown());
        for (String groupName : schedule.getJobGroupNames()) {
            for (JobKey jobKey : schedule.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher
                    .jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {
                String jobName = jobKey.getName();
                String jobGroup = jobKey.getGroup();
                List<Trigger> triggers = (List<Trigger>) schedule
                        .getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
                Date nextFireTime = triggers.get(0).getNextFireTime();
                System.out.println("[jobName] : " + jobName + " [groupName] : "
                        + jobGroup + " - " + nextFireTime);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Although, there are few jobs, which are keep on running using web application struts2.

Comment: Does it print out a size of the group names?

Answer (score 0):

The call to [getScheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/) is providing you with a new scheduler, which does not contain the jobs.  You need to get a handle to the scheduler containing the actual jobs, through one of two ways.

Iterate through all schedulers:

```
  for(Scheduler schedule :StdSchedulerFactory().getAllSchedulers()){
            System.out.println(schedule.getJobGroupNames().size()+" "+schedule.isShutdown());
            for (String groupName : schedule.getJobGroupNames()) {
                for (JobKey jobKey : schedule.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher
                        .jobGroupEquals(groupName))) {
                    String jobName = jobKey.getName();
                    String jobGroup = jobKey.getGroup();
                    List<Trigger> triggers = (List<Trigger>) schedule
                            .getTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
                    Date nextFireTime = triggers.get(0).getNextFireTime();
                    System.out.println("[jobName] : " + jobName + " [groupName] : "
                            + jobGroup + " - " + nextFireTime);
                }

            }
    }
```

Or getting a scheduler by name:

```
Scheduler schedule = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler("schedulerName");
```

Comment: First approach wasn't helpful, whereas I'm confuse about `schedulerName`

Comment: One of two things is happening.  Either no jobs are scheduled or your not getting the proper scheduler instance.  The code you provided works: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/9554506

Comment: I followed steps from here http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-quartz-scheduler-integration-example/

Comment: I have gone through your code, there I have one query. Will it work, if we will put `execute` function to other class and call independently ?

Comment: I haven't tested but I believe it should.

Comment: No.. It's not working.. So, I think, that's the reason,I'm not getting list. It seems, I can't use Quartz for webapps.

Comment: @jWeaver I have definitely used Quartz for web apps

Comment: @jWeaver Placing the job outside works for me: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/9555850

Comment: I don't know, why this is not working for me. Can you please suggest me any tutorial, where I can find steps to do (add jobs and listing them) this on netbeans